# Performance tradeoffs with junction table as opposed to a foreign key array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

how does one know when to use an array for foreign keys vs a junction table? (which will achieve better performance in which scenarios) IE if i know i only have the 12 months as my foreign key i would assume that the array would perform better. **Does anyone know how to justify when one would perform better than the other? are there things to look for?**

like if the many to many relationship exists where each one only has typically 5 foreign keys. what about 10. how about 1000, etc. when do you make the call to stop using a junction table and use an array?

**I am not looking for opionions. I am looking for ways in which to determine how to measure or make a call for what is the better performance choice.**

Answer (score 4):

If you have a many-to-many table, you should always use a junction table.  If you have a one to many relationship you should have parent child tables. What you shoudl virtually never have is a table with fields like: Phone1, Phone2, Phone3.